# in XSL remove path from filename in variable

Tags: xslt

I'm working in Oxygen and am using Saxon.

I'm searching through a bunch of xml files in search of jpg names. I'm creating 
variables as follows:

```
<xsl:variable name="allxml" 
select="collection('..//xml/?select=*.xml;recurse=yes')"/>
<xsl:variable name="jpgs" select="$allxml//element/@n"/>
```

$jpgs looks like:

dir1/jpg001.jpg dir1/jpg002.jpg dir1/jpg003.jpg

etc.

I want to strip away the dir info, but I am having a hard time. I've tried using 
`tokenize()` and `substring-after()`, but both return similar errors.

> "A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of 
>   fn:tokenize() ("dir1/jpg001.jpg", "dir1/jpg002.jpg" "dir1/jpg003.jpg")."

Because I don't know what I'm doing, I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help me figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show your code, but from the error message it sounds as if you tried to apply `tokenize($jpgs)`.

The error message is telling you that the first parameter to `tokenize()` needs to be a single string, but you are giving it a sequence of strings.

You need to apply `tokenize()` to each item in the sequence of `$jpgs` values.

You could use `xsl:for-each` to iterator over the items in the sequence:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$jpgs">
  <xsl:sequence select="tokenize(., '/')[last()] "/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

or you could use a for expression:

```
<xsl:sequence select="for $path in $jpgs return tokenize($path, '/')[last()] "/>
```